# Vertex information from FBX in XNA, strange results

Tags: 3d, xna, vertex-buffer, fbx

I'm trying to grab the vertex position data from an fbx file, for testing I'm using a simple plane, it lies in the xz plane and it's 4 vertices are (+/-1, 0, +/-1). The vertex data is confirmed in Maya, which I used to export the plane.

Here's my vertex extraction code:

```
void getVertices()
{
    foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
        foreach (ModelMeshPart part in mesh.MeshParts)
        {
            nVerts = part.NumVertices;
            Vector3[] vec = new Vector3[nVerts * 2];

            part.VertexBuffer.GetData<Vector3>(vec);

            Console.WriteLine("#Vertices in Model: " + nVerts);
            for (int i = 0; i < vec.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i + " " vec[i].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Since there are 4 vertices, I get 8 Vector3s, 1 for each vertex position and one for each vertex normal. For the plane MOST are correct (I used more complicated models at first and it was less accurate).

Here are the results: all the normals should point straight up in Y.

Points:
(1,0,-1)
(1,0,1)
(1,0,1)
(-1,0,1)

Normals
(0,1,0)
(0,1,0)
(1,-1,0)
(0,0,0)

The third point, (the same as the 2nd) and the final 2 normals are wrong. I can't figure out why I am not getting the right data. I've tried increasing the vector3 array, but it only has 8 vectors to send, so i don't think I'm missing any info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you loaded the FBX through the content pipeline, it would have assigned it one of the frameworks standard vertex types. But there is no vertex type that has only position and normal information. Most likely there is a 3rd element that is screwing up your results. This should work:

```
int vertexStride = model.Meshes[0].MeshParts[0].VertexDeclaration.VertexStride;
VertexBuffer vb = model.Meshes[0].MeshParts[0].VertexBuffer;
List<Vector3> vertexPositions = new List<Vector3>();


for(int i = 0; i < vb.VertexCount; i++)
{
   Vector3 vec;
   vb.GetData<Vector3>(i*vertexStride, vec, i, 1, vertexStride);//3rd param should either be i or 0
   vertexPositions.Add(vec);
}
```

Comment: this worked, thanks a lot!

I found out the index Buffer changes every model through even if it's from the same program, which I wouldn't have thought, and there were a few small syntax errors, So I'll post what I ended up with below for completeness the next guy. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Models can have different vertex structures, so the best is consider its info to read the data, if you wnat textures or normal the best is using the right VertexElementUsage to check if it exists and what is the offset where data is.

```
var vertices = new float[  meshPart.VertexBuffer.VertexCount 
                         * meshPart.VertexBuffer.VertexDeclaration.VertexStride / 4];

meshPart.VertexBuffer.GetData<float>( vertices );

var vertexElements = meshPart.VertexBuffer.VertexDeclaration.GetVertexElements( );

int vertexOffset = vertexElements
        .First( e => e.VertexElementUsage == VertexElementUsage.Position )
        .Offset / 4;

for (int i = meshPart.VertexOffset; 
         i < meshPart.VertexOffset + meshPart.NumVertices; i++ {
    int baseIndex = i * (meshPart.VertexBuffer.VertexDeclaration.VertexStride / 4);

    var X = vertices[baseIndex + vertexOffset] ;
    var Y = vertices[baseIndex + vertexOffset + 1];
    var Z = vertices[baseIndex + vertexOffset + 2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My final answer, based on the help I got from Steve H, and including index data:

```
    VertexBuffer vertexBuffer;
    VertexPositionColor[] verts;
    IndexBuffer indexBuffer;
    short[] indices;
    int nVerts;

    void getVertices()
        {
            int vertexStride = model.Meshes[0].MeshParts[0].VertexBuffer.VertexDeclaration.VertexStride;
            vertexBuffer = model.Meshes[0].MeshParts[0].VertexBuffer;
            nVerts = vertexBuffer.VertexCount;

            indexBuffer = model.Meshes[0].MeshParts[0].IndexBuffer;
            int nInts = indexBuffer.IndexCount;

            indices = new short[nInts];

            indexBuffer.GetData<short>(indices);

            verts = new VertexPositionColor[vertexBuffer.VertexCount];

            for (int i = 0; i < vertexBuffer.VertexCount; i++)
            {
                Vector3[] vertData = new Vector3[vertexBuffer.VertexCount];
                vertexBuffer.GetData<Vector3>(i * vertexStride, vertData, i, 1, vertexStride);

                verts[i].Position = vertData[i];
            }

            vertexBuffer = new VertexBuffer(device, typeof(VertexPositionColor), nVerts, BufferUsage.WriteOnly);
            indexBuffer = new IndexBuffer(device, typeof(short), nVerts / 4 * 6, BufferUsage.WriteOnly);

            vertexBuffer.SetData(verts);
            indexBuffer.SetData(indices);

        }
```

Comment: Gettting data as Vector3 is a bad idea if you want to access other data... TextureCoordinates are vector2, Colors are Vector4... though it solve your needs... I think that is better to retrieve data as float and use VertexElementUsage to detect the right offset position of the data you want...

Comment: yes, thanks, i didn't see your answer until I had finished my own. Once I get the 3d models working well in my particle system, I'm going to go back and implement it your way.